# How can I tell if an EC2 instance is inside my VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, starcluster

My client has many EC2 instances running, and a VPC (virtual private cloud) running.

I'm using a platform called Starcluster to launch nodes, and I need to know if they're in the VPC or just ordinary EC2 nodes. How can I do that?

Amazon's VPC console at this address:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1

shows:
1 VPC
3 Running Instances

but some of those running instances are non-VPC instances, as far as I know. Hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On AWS Console you can see it. Just like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you select an instance in the [EC2 Instances screen](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Instances%3a), you can see a bunch of fields under the Description tab. Look for a field called "VPC ID". If there is no value for that field, it is not in a VPC.